# SEM calculation in R or SPSS

Tags: spss

I want to calculate the Standard Error of Measurement for my reliability analysis.

SEM = SD * sqrt(1-R)

In order to do so I need the variance or standard deviation. I have 3 raters and 12 subjects. 
(It was not possible to add the data because I cannot insert a table)

When performing a reliability analysis in SPSS I have the option to output the scale statistics, which give me the variance and standard deviation. However, this variance is completly different than when using the ICC function in R.

Since the variance values in R differ so much I am not sure which one is right. The ICC's I found are similar between both programs.
Does anyone have experience with calculating the SEM using SPSS or R?

Answer (score 0):

In SPSS you would need to calculate the SEM "manually" using the reliability estimate and the scale standard deviation. I'm not sure what R's icc reports for variances and standard deviations, but RELIABILITY in SPSS sums the item values for each case as the scale values, so it reports the variances and standard deviations of these sums of variables. Perhaps R reports things in terms of means of the variables instead.